# How to add actions to a button in java

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have been working with java buttons, and I have created a button ,but when i click the button, I want the shape of the object to change. This is the code I've worked on

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class shapes {
public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Change shapes");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton b = new JButton("Shapes Change");
    f.getContentPane().add(b);
    f.pack();      
    f.setVisible(true);




}

Public void paint (Graphics g)
{
   //no clue what to do here

}
private static abstract class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
MyButton()
{
    addActionListener(this);
}

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (e.getSource() == b)
         {

                //no clue what to do here

            }
}
}
}
```

At first, There is a shape created, once the button is clicked it I want to change it to another shape.

Comment: nobody knows about your specification, so you should tell us what you want to do not us tell u

Answer (score 3):

There really shouldn't be any need to subclass `JButton`.  If you want to customise the button, you could use the `Action` API instead, see [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

To perform custom painting your should extend a Swing component like `JComponent` or `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent` method...

See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

You would then need to provide some method which you could call to tell the component that the shape should change to how the shape should be changed.

You would then provide a means for your buttons `ActionListener` to reference the instance of the paint panel and call these methods...

Answer (score 0):

You simply add an `ActionListener` to the button:

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do some action
    }
});
```

A couple other things to note:

1. You should not run Swing methods outside the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) or you may run into unpredictable errors.
2. [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) specify that class names should be capitalized. In your code, you named the class "shapes" but it is more proper to name it "Shapes".

Answer (score 0):

First declare and define methods for drawing objects.  For example drawSquare (), drawCircle () which draws required shapes. Define radio button or something similar to that to get the users choice (to know which object has to be drawn) . In actionPerformed () check which radiobutton is selected and call the appropriate method for drawing objects and call the repaint () for updating in user interface